# Setting a specific selected value in a Simple Form select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, default, simple-form

I have a select box filled with options for a specific album type:

```
<select class="select optional" name="album[album_type_id]" id="album_album_type_id">
  <option value="1">Collaborative Album</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">Compilation Album</option>
  <option value="2">EP</option>
  <option value="3">Soundtrack</option>
  <option value="4">Studio Album</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to set `Studio Album` as the default value. I understand I could do the following:

```
<%= f.input :album_type_id, as: :select, collection: @album_types, selected: 4 %>
```

but more album types are bound to be added in the future and would much rather target it's string literal title. What would be the best way approach in using this for SimpleForms 'selected` parameter?

Comment: Are the album types populated from the database? Or hard-coded HTML?

Comment: Populated from the database. Wrote the html output just to give readers an idea on how things were rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree on previous answer being the ideal. In the meantime, I'd use a helper:

```
<%= f.input :album_type_id, as: :select, collection: @album_types, selected: get_index_by_name(@albums, 'Studio Album') %>
```

Then in helpers/album_helper.rb:

```
module AlbumHelper
  def get_index_by_name(albums, name)
    albums.first { |album| album.name == name }.id
  end 
end
```

Or as it's an instance variable you could do this, but maybe it's less reusable:

```
<%= f.input :album_type_id, as: :select, collection: @album_types, selected: get_album_index_of('Studio Album') %>
```

Then the helper:

```
module AlbumHelper
  def get_album_index_of(name)
    @albums.first { |album| album.name == name }.id
  end 
end
```

Or perhaps a generic one to use across the whole site if there will be other dropdowns:

```
<%= f.input :album_type_id, as: :select, collection: @album_types, selected: get_index_by_attribute(@albums, :name, 'Studio Album') %>
```

In application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_index_by_attribute(collection, attribute, value)
    collection.first { |item| item.send(attribute) == value }.id
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the myriad of solutions. Never knew that code blocks could be passed in the `first()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
<%= f.input :album_type_id, as: :select, priority: ['Studio Album'], collection: @album_types %>
```

I can't test it out right now but I know the collections for countries can be prioritized like above (it's even in the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#priority)). I don't see why it wouldn't work for your specific scenario.

### EDIT

You are right - I've taken a look at the source and the priorities are tied to the specific `:country` and `:time_zone` inputs. To get at what you want, you'd either have to find out which `id` is the one for your collection that you want prioritized, or you could make a [custom input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs) and implement the priority functionality the way the code does for those two inputs. I suppose it depends on your needs. A helper that returns the `id` would probably be the way to go for a simple solution.

Comment: This makes for a fabulous pull request on it -makes no sense to have this functionality split out.